# Double icons with twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a form in Bootsrap 3.37  when I noticed that one of my icons was repeating. I checked the code but its not in there twice.

An example of the code is:

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Simpson, Dan</b> - <br> 217 Old Ocean Drive Des Moines 50310</td>
    <td>45885552</td>
    <td>Feb 24 2018</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>1
        <td>
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="../../wine/admin/index.cfm/index.cfm/general/getRecentOrderAjax?method=getRecentOrderAjax&order_id=19" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></a>


        </td>
</tr>
```

See fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/103724/

Other libraries used are:
 Data tables - https://datatables.net/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you missed the end tag for i element:

you code is:

```
    <td>
    <a data-toggle="modal" href="../../wine/admin/index.cfm/index.cfm/general/getRecentOrderAjax?method=getRecentOrderAjax&order_id=2" data-target="#myModal">
<i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true">
</a>
</td>
```

and should it be:

```
<td>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href="../../wine/admin/index.cfm/index.cfm/general/getRecentOrderAjax?method=getRecentOrderAjax&order_id=2" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the closing `</i>` tag.

In your example your output should be like this

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="../../wine/admin/index.cfm/index.cfm/general/getRecentOrderAjax?method=getRecentOrderAjax&order_id=19" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Comment: Facepalm. Too much time looking at the code and forgetting the simple things. Thanks!

Comment: No worries happens to anyone :)